# VB.Net Clone a Control

Tags: vb.net

This is the code I am using to clone a control before I add it to my groupbox (trying to clone from my existing label lblPriDB):

```
lbl = New Windows.Forms.Label()

 For Each oPropertyInfo As System.Reflection.PropertyInfo In lbl.GetType().GetProperties()
        If oPropertyInfo.CanWrite Then
          oPropertyInfo.SetValue(lbl, oPropertyInfo.GetValue(lblPriDB, Nothing), Nothing)
        End If    
  Next

 lbl.Name = lbl.Name + iCount.ToString
 grpBox.Controls.Add(lbl)
 lbl.Location = New Point(lblPriDB.Location.X, 250)
```

Something in the for loop is freezing up my UI, and the grpBox.Controls.Add(lbl) command is not actually adding the label. I have tried to figure this out but there are too many properties, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Cloning a Winforms control is not possible.  It has entirely too much runtime state that cannot be copied.  There is code somewhere that created that original control.  Move it into a method, now you can simply run it again.

Comment: what do you mean by too much runtime state

Comment: In your case, cloning control probably means getting a control with some main properties, like `Text`, `Checked`, etc. So, why don't you make list of properties that you will want to clone and use that list as driver, and check if control has that property and set it.